# Elementary proof of existence of integral kernel

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory

I know the following statement is true.

> Let $T \in B(L^1(\mathbb{R}^d), L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d))$, where $B(X, Y)$ denotes all bounded linear operators from $X$ to $Y$.
> Then, $T$ has the integral kernel $k(x,y) \in L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}^d)$,
> that is, for all $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and for almost all $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$,
> \begin{equation}
> Tf(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} k(x, y)f(y) dy.
> \end{equation}
> Furthermore, $\|T\|_{B(L^1, L^\infty)} = \|k\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^{2d})}$.

This is a corollary of Theorem 2.2.5 of the following article:

N. Dunford and B. J. Pettis "Linear operations on summable functions", *Trans. Amer. Math. Soc.* 47, (1940), 323–392.
https://www.jstor.org/stable/1989960?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents

However, this article is written in a very abstract style. I would like to know more elementary proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Consider
\begin{equation}
\phi(g\otimes f) = \int_{{\mathbb R}^d} g(x) (Tf)(x) dx\in {\mathbb R}
\end{equation}
then extend $\phi$ by continuity (and linearity) to a continuous linear functional on $L^1({{\mathbb R}^d}\times{{\mathbb R}^d})$. Then use that the dual of $L^1({{\mathbb R}^d}\times{{\mathbb R}^d})$ is $L^{\infty}({{\mathbb R}^d}\times{{\mathbb R}^d})$.